# Countability of set of jump discontinuities of a function

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Prove that a function can only have at most countable points of jump discontinuities.
I tried this way and want to know that if this is correct or not. Please help
$$$$Consider a function $f(x)$ and  consider the set $$E_n =\left\{c : \left|\lim_{x \to c^-}f(x)-\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)\right|>\frac{1}{n}\right\}\,.$$ Let us chose any $c \in E_n$ then we claim that $c$ is an isolated point of $E_n$. Suppose this is not true then for every $k$ there exists a $$c_k \in \left(c-\frac{1}{k}, c+\frac{1}{k}\right)\,,$$ such that $$\left|\lim_{x \to (c_ k)^-}f(x)-\lim_{x \to (c_ k)^+}f(x)\right|>\frac{1}{n}\,.$$ Now as we can see $c_k$ converges to $c$ and hence infinitely many members of $c_k$ lie on either left or the right of $c$, so WLOG let us assume that infinitely many members of $c_k$ lie to the right side of $c$. Now as $c \in E_n$ so let $$\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)=L_1\,,$$ then for $\epsilon =\frac{1}{3n}$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x, y \in (c, c+\delta)$ we have $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{1}{3n}\,.$$ Also as $c_k$ converges to $c$, so there exists a $K$ such that for all $k > K$ we have $$c_k \in (c, c+\delta)\,.$$ Now chose a $k_0>K$ such that $$c_{k_0} \in (c, c+\delta)\,.$$ Now as $c_{k_0} \in E_n$ so we can choose a $x_0<c_{k_0}$ and $x_0 \in (c, c+\delta)$ such that $$\left|f(x_0)-\lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^-}f(x)\right|<\frac{1}{3n}\,,$$ similarly we can chose a $y_0>c_{k_0}$ and $y_0 \in (c, c+\delta)$ such that $$\left|f(y_0)-\lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^+}f(x)\right|<\frac{1}{3n}\,.$$ Now consider

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}&<\left|\lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^+}f(x) - \lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^-}f(x)\right|\\
&\leq \left|\lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^+}f(x)-f(y_0)\right| + |f(y_0)-f(x_0)|\\
&\qquad+ \left|f(x_0) - \lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^-}f(x)\right|\\
&< \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{1}{3n}\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\,,\end{align*}$$

a contradiction. Hence every point in $E_n$ is an isolated point and hence $E_n$ is a countable set. Also all the points at which $f(x)$ has a Jump discontinuity is covered by the sets $E_n$ where $n$ varies over all the natural numbers. And hence the set of points of jump discontinuities of $f(x)$ is countable.

Comment: I think the indicator function on rational numbers has uncountable jump discontinuities.

Comment: No the domain is entire set of real numbers

Comment: Define $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$ The domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think you meant this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Froda%27s_theorem

Comment: The function you have given has no jump discontinuities, by jump discontinuities i mean theat both the LHL and RHL shpuld exist at that point

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @Idonknow . For $x$ to be a jump point of $f$, it is necessary, by def'n, that $\lim_{y\to x^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{y\to x+}f(x)$ both exist (but are unequal).

Comment: Well done.............................